# strange return from python's f.read

Tags: python, file-io

I am trying to capture some data from a piece of hardware I'm developing through one of cypress' fx2lp chips. I used cypress' software to record a sample of my data stream to a file, which I am trying to read with python. However, when I read it, I'm getting some interesting output that I'm not sure how to interpret.

I am opening the file like this:

```
f = open("testdata_5Aug2014.dat","rb")
```

Then I read the data in various sized chunks, similar to this:

```
f.read(100)
```

Typically, the result of the above line (and what I want to see) is something like this:

```
'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x05\x12\x05\x12\x05\x12\x05\x12\x05\x12\x05\x12\x05\x12\x05\x12\x05\x12\x05\x12\x05\x12\x05\x12\x05\x12\x05\x12\x05\x12\x05\x12\x05\x12\x05\x12\x05\x12\x05\x12\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
```

But I sometimes get returns that include 't's and '?'s thrown in there like this:

```
'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00t\x14t\x14t\x14t\x14t\x14t\x14t\x14t\x14t\x14t\x14t\x14t\x14t\x14t\x14t\x14t\x14t\x14t\x14t\x14t\x14K\x01?\x00\xff??\x00\xff??\x00\xff??\x00\xff?\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
```

This is a problem, because when I use struct.unpack to parse this out, it won't return any of those bytes with the special characters appended.

So my question is: What are those symbols? How did they get there? and How do I remove them or deal with them?

Comment: Are you sure it's not just e.g. `'\x74'` being interpreted as `'t'` and `'\x3f'` as `'?'`?

Comment: I have no idea what it is, that's why I'm here. That seems very plausible because I know there are a lot of x3f's in this file particularly following xff.

Comment: Have you actually had problems with `struct.unpack`?

Comment: I don't think so. This is the raw output from f.read(). I'm thinking that I'm somehow reading the file incorrectly. I was hoping someone may have seen this before and would be able to steer me in the right direction.

Comment: I think this is *just a display issue*; Python interprets those bytes as characters. I suggest you ignore it and only worry if further processing fails on those characters.

Comment: I guess you're right. I tried numpy.fromfile() and it gives me the results I expect. I borrowed that struct.unpack code from some other code and I guess it doesn't apply here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're reading binary data from a file, but `f.read` returns that data as a string. When you print that string, it's interpreting those bytes as characters. However, not every byte value maps to a displayable character, so some bytes are shown as escape sequences: `\x` followed by two hexadecimal digits. For example, 0 shows up as `\x00` and 255 shows up as `\xff`.

Some values do map to characters, such as 63 mapping to '?' and 116 mapping to 't'. The `ord` and `chr` functions can be used to fetch the numerical value of a character, and the character mapping for a number, respectively, so `ord('t')` returns 116 and `chr(63)` returns `'?'`.

Either way, no matter how it's displayed, your data should be fine, and `struct.unpack` should be able to work with it as usual.